# Edit and reopen - shows reopen popup but doesn't let me edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen

I've just seen a question in the new Reopen queue that needed editting - the user had added code, but it was missing linebreaks.

I clicked on Edit and Reopen. I got the 'Nominate this question for reopening' popup; clicked on OK; and my vote was then counted without me getting the Edit box.